# Duplicated builds from the initial PR being opened with custom label to trigger GithubAction

Tags: expo, github-actions, eas

When I push changes to my GitHub PR, which has GitHubActions set to trigger EAS builds, sometimes I see duplicated builds with the `development-internal` profile.

I can see it's the same commit hash:
[image]
[image]

We are on:

- Managed Workflow
- `eas-cli` version: `eas-version: latest`
- expo SDK46

Here is the `eas.config`:

```
{
  "build": {
    "staging": {
      "node": "16.15.0",
      "yarn": "1.22.5",
      "env": {
        "API_ADDRESS": "ourURL",
        "LOG_API_ERRORS": "true",
        "GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY": "ourKey"
      },
      "ios": {
        "env": {
          "PLATFORM": "ios"
        }
      }
    },
    "prod": {
      "node": "16.15.0",
      "yarn": "1.22.5",
     "env": {
        "API_ADDRESS": "ourURL",
        "LOG_API_ERRORS": "true",
        "GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY": "ourKey"
      },
      "ios": {
        "env": {
          "PLATFORM": "ios"
        }
      }
    },
    "release": {},
    "prod-internal": {
      "extends": "prod",
      "releaseChannel": "prod-internal",
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "development-internal": {
      "extends": "staging",
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "development-simulator": {
      "extends": "prod",
      "ios": {
        "releaseChannel": "development-simulator",
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "extends": "staging",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and our GitHub workflow `ci.yml`:

```
name: CI
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled, opened, synchronize]
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  typescript:
    name: Compile Typescript
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout GitHub Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set Up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          cache: yarn
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org

      - name: Install Deps
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

      - name: Validate TypeScript
        run: yarn tsc

  lint:
    name: Lint code
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

      - name: Install deps
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

      - name: Validate Lint
        run: yarn lint

  jest:
    name: Run unit tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

      - name: Install deps
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

      - name: Validate Unit Tests
        run: yarn test

  build_ios:
    name: Build IPA file on EAS
    if: ${{ contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'ready for review') }}
    needs:
      - typescript
      - lint
      - jest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      id: ${{ steps.iosBuild.outputs.id }}
      url: ${{ steps.iosBuild.outputs.url }}
    steps:
      - name:  Setup repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name:  Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          cache: yarn
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

      - name:  Setup Expo and EAS
        uses: expo/expo-github-action@v7
        with:
          expo-version: 5.x
          eas-version: latest
          token: ${{ secrets.EXPO_TOKEN }}

      - name:  Install dependencies
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

      - name:  Build IPA
        id: iosBuild
        run: |
          eas build --platform ios --non-interactive --profile development-internal --json > build_ios.json
          echo "::set-output name=id::$(jq '.[] .id' build_ios.json -r)"
          echo "::set-output name=url::$(jq '.[] .artifacts.buildUrl' build_ios.json -r)"

  pr_comment:
    if: ${{ contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'ready for review') }}
    needs:
      - build_ios
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Comment PR
        uses: unsplash/comment-on-pr@v1.3.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          msg: |
            Build successfully created. Here are the URLs:
            -  iOS Build URL - https://expo.dev/accounts/fluidtruck/projects/delta/builds/${{ needs.build_ios.outputs.id }}
          check_for_duplicate_msg: false
          delete_prev_regex_msg: "Build successfully created. Here are the URLs"
```

is there something wrong with the EAS.config?

Comment: types: [labeled, opened, synchronize] Are u adding a label while opening a PR?

Answer (score 0):

When we open a PR with a label it seems to trigger duplicate.

I changed this to:

```
    types: [labeled, synchronize]
```

and it seems to be better now.  It's odd though, another repo has the original types with `opened` and it doesn't duplicate...